# HAC estimator in GARCH models

Tags: time-series, stationarity, garch, robust-standard-error

In my time-series class we learned that the HAC estimator is only applicable to correct the standard error (SE) if the underlying series is stationary. Now, GARCH models are unconditionally stationary (under certain conditions that are given let's say), however, they are conditionally non-stationary. Does this mean that we can apply the HAC estimator to the coefficients in the GARCH equations or not?

Furthermore, there was a question in my class that I cannot find an answer to:
Consider the model $X_{t} = \mu + Y_{t}$, where $Y_{t}$ is a stationary GARCH(1,1) process with mean zero. When computing the confidence interval for $\mu$, can the HAC adjusted SE for the mean of $X_{t}$ be applied or not?

Comment: What do you mean by *conditionally non-stationary*?

Comment: By conditionally non-stationary I mean that the conditional variance $\sigma_{t}^2$ in the GARCH model $Y_{t}=\sigma_{t}\epsilon_{t}$ depends on time.

Comment: Now, for the second question: I have two contradicting approaches. The first is, since the process is unconditionally stationary, we should be able to use the HAC estimator. On second thought, however, the HAC uses the limiting variance of $X_{t}$ and therefore also uses the covariance, which only measure the linear dependence. In a GARCH model, which is non-linear, this might lead to an inconsistent estimator if we apply the HAC estimator (based only on linear dependence). So, I do not really know how to approach this question.

Comment: In a GARCH model, the dependence of $\sigma_t$ is on past values rather than time. It is true that $\sigma_t$ varies over time, though. By analogy, consider regression with ARMA errors. ARMA models could be called *conditionally non-stationary* by your definition, as the conditional mean is determined by past values. We can use HAC in that case. (I do not have a definite answer to your question, but I am trying to draw some parallels.)

Comment: I have found a somewhat different take on the matter, which I think makes a lot of sense. We know that the conditional variance is given by $\sigma_{t}^2=\gamma + \alpha Y_{t-1}^2 + \beta\sigma_{t-1}^2$ for a GARCH(1,1) model. Therefore, the SE required for the confidence intervals should simply be $\sqrt{\sigma_{t}^2}$ and thus we would not need to adjust the SE any further. What do you think about this?

Comment: What still bothers me though, is the fact that this SE also depends on time, so I am not sure if it can really be used for inference.

Comment: I think your approach, and also my intuition tending towards being able to use the HAC, is what I am going with. However, I would still like to have some sort of certainty...

Comment: Yes, that does make sense, though that assumes the model is correct. HAC is a model-free approach. Regarding HAC vs. a model-specific approach, see https://fxdiebold.blogspot.com/2015/10/the-hac-emperor-has-no-clothes.html and https://fxdiebold.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-hac-emperor-has-no-clothes-part-2.html.

Comment: I know about this, but if we do not assume a model then the problem of the non-linearity in the GARCH model seems to become relevant, right?

Comment: How is nonlinearity relevant here?

Comment: Well, because the HAC adjusted SE for the mean is based on the covariance of the underlying process, which only measures linear dependence. The GARCH process, however, is non-linear. I am not sure if this is a problem, but it seems a bit counterintuitive to use the covariance (i.e. linear dependence) to adjust a SE in a non-linear setting.

Comment: I see. But doesn't the H in HAC stand for heteroskedasticity? It should then work for heteroskedastic errors, too.

Comment: That is very true! I guess everything points in the direction of the HAC estimator being applicable here. Thanks a lot for your inputs!

Comment: Be careful. You usually need to make assumptions about fourth [moments](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/moments) when you prove the consistency of HAC. And the fourth moments of GARCH are not always finite (depends on the parameters; there are several papers on finiteness conditions)